# Template returns true() when is told to return false

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Why am I getting true as a return value from this template:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:template name="return-false">
  <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
   <xsl:variable name="call-template">
    <xsl:call-template name="return-false"/>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:if test="$call-template = true()">
    <FALSE/>
   </xsl:if>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Guess what I am getting on the output document **FALSE element**. I am wondering should I cry or should I laugh on my struggle on this simple example. My frustration hit the sky.

Comment: how about providing your XML input and output.

Comment: I believe it is simple enough to be understood without those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `xsl:value-of` instruction creates a text node.

```
<xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
```

returns the **string-value** of the `false()` function, which is the string "false". So the content of your `$call-template` variable is a text node containing the string "false".

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#value-of

Next, the test `test="$call-template = true()"` returns `true()`, because:

- you are comparing a text node to a boolean;
- a node compared to a boolean is first converted to a boolean;
- a node that exists is evaluated as `true()` when converted to a boolean.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans

Answer (score 2):

Note that in XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 a template or function can return a boolean value but not using `value-of`, instead using `sequence` e.g.

```
<xsl:template name="return-false">
    <xsl:sequence select="false()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, typically you would not return a boolean constant value but instead simply evaluate a comparison e.g.

```
<xsl:template name="check">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="matches($input, 'foo')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, to use such code in a compact form, you would write a function

```
<xsl:function name="mf:check">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="matches($input, 'foo')"/>
</xsl:function>
```

and call it with e.g. `<xsl:variable name="check1" select="mf:check('foobar')"/>` respectively `<xsl:if test="mf:check('foobar')">..</xsl:if>`.

Answer (score 1):

Test against the value `'true'` or `'false'` rather than the function and it works.  Why are you doing it this way though?  What are you trying to achieve?  Using a `call-template` to return a boolean value is more of a procedural thing, and likely not to fit well with the more functional/declarative model of XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template name="return-false">
        <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:variable name="call-template">
                <xsl:call-template name="return-false"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$call-template = 'true'">
                <FALSE/>
            </xsl:if>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are correct, but what is the reason for not working my way?

Comment: See @michael.hor257k's answer - he got to that first

Comment: There's nothing intrinsically procedural or non-declarative in having a template return a boolean value. It's just that it can't be done in XSLT 1.0; templates in 1.0 always return nodes (or, in the language of the 1.0 spec, write nodes to the result tree, which in this case is the result tree fragment created by the xsl:variable).

Comment: I guess I'm imagining it being used in the context of trying to treat a call-template like a boolean function.  It just seems more functional to me.